# Split Data from Wordpress Database

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, database, installation

On my initial setup, I had installed CiviCRM onto the same database as the Wordpress installation.
Now I want to split this as I am migrating the website and would rather backup and have a copy of the CiviCRM installation on its own.
Does anyone have any advice on how this could be accomplished?
Can I just backup the existing DB and restore to a new instance and it would all just work?

Comment: feel i have seen similar questions before though it may have been in chat

Answer (score 6):

That's really two operations: splitting the combined db to separate WP and Civi ones, and migrating.  For the migration part [see the manual](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-servers/).

To split the db, you could make a duplicate of the original as the Civi db (dump and load), then in the Civi one delete all the non-civi tables and in the original/WP one, delete all the civi tables.  In your `civicrm.settings.php` file find the setting for `CIVICRM_DSN` and change it to use the new database name.

Make sure you keep a backup of your original combined db just in case!

Comment: So doing that wouldn't break the integration with the WordPress backend?